# Test glob against an arbitrary string in zsh?

Tags: zsh, glob

Is it possible to test whether a string matches a glob in zsh?  This would be completely independent of file paths.  Specifically, I am wondering whether there is a command (call it `testglob`) that allows me to check whether a string would be considered a match to the glob, like so:

```
testglob '^s*' string_that_matches
testglob '^s*' does_not_match
```

I would expect different return values for these two commands.

If this does not already exist, it would be a great feature to consider for addition.  It would allow external applications to access zsh's globbing system without having to emulate its globbing rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[[ ... ]]` command does this, with the regular `==` operator.

```
if [[ string == s* ]]; then
   echo string starts with s
fi
```